# How to call Python variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, html, json, django

I have a Python function that returns some value. Also I connected to my project Google Charts. So I need to pass that value to a js function in html file of Google Charts. The project is on Django btw.

What is the most correct way to do this?

```
{%  extends "gappi_tmp/wrapper.html" %}

{% block content %}

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['lol',11], // The variable should be here, instead of '11'
          ['Eat',   11] // Here another variable
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Inbox | Outbox'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }


    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="padding-top: 5px; background: cornflowerblue; width: auto; height: 300px;" id="piechart"></div>
  </body>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should render your template with a *context*:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context

The method of passing the context to the template depends on how your views are written.

**Function-based views**

Pass the *context* dictionary to the `render()` function:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#optional-arguments

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def my_view(request):
    # View code here...
    context = {'foo': 'bar'}
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', context=context)
```

**Class-based views**

Write your own implementation of the `add_context_data()` method: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from books.models import Book, Publisher

class PublisherDetail(DetailView):

    model = Publisher

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add in a QuerySet of all the books
        context['book_list'] = Book.objects.all()
        return context
```

Once you passed `key: value` context to the template, you should use it in the template like this: `{{ key }}`.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/templates/#variables

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   var a = "{{ key|escapejs }}";
</script>
```

[escapejs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#escapejs) template filter is required to prevent possible XSS vulnerabilities. If you need to pass JSON, you could check out Django ticket [#17419](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17419)

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to **access python vars in a separated js file**. You can define js global vars with the value of python vars, then access those global vars in a separated js file.

Answer (score 0):

Generate the above page dynamically in Django including the necessary json data object from your python code

from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/)

Answer (score 0):

**In case that you have you `js` file inside your html file**, and **not in a seperated js file**, since variables passed through context are available in the rendering templates, you can proceed  that way.

> After sending all the variables via context to template.

```
var jsVariable = '{{django_value}}';

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Task', '{{ task_variable }}'], // as string
    ['lol',{{lol_variable}}], // as integer
    ['Eat',   {{eat_variable}} ]
]);
```

You can also loop through.

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    {% for item in queryset %} // {% for item in json_response %}
        ['Task', '{{ task.attribute }}'],
    {% endfor %}  // {% endfor %}
]);
```

Basically, you must know that you can use it, it depends of what you really want to do.